# Password in wp-config. Dangerous?

Tags: wp-config

I don't know a lot of Wordpress yet, and I'm just wondering:

Before installation you have to fill in the correct data in `wp-config-sample.php` but this also includes the database password. Isn't that dangerous? I mean, can some one explain how this is protected from just reading the file and thus getting the password of your DB?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "Hardening WordPress" page of the Codex contains a section on ["Securing wp-config.php"](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#securing-wp-config-php). It includes changing the permissions to 440 or 400. You can also move the wp-config file one directory up from the root if your server configuration allows for that.

Of course there is some danger to having a file with the password like this if someone gets access to your server, but, honestly, at that point they already are in your server.

Finally, you don't have much of a choice. I've never seen an alternate means of configuring WordPress. You can lock it down as much as you can, but this is how WordPress is built, and if it were a **serious** security threat, they wouldn't do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for that link! I can see a lot of security precautions there. Should one apply all of them? Or isn't anything of that really necessary?

Comment: I don't know that one can ever have too much [well-implemented] security.

Comment: @mrwweb +1 for *well*implemented*.

Comment: Isn't it possible to override database initialization by creating a db.php file and setting $wpdb there? This would bypass the config value for the database password.

Answer (score 9):

To make a case for keeping your config file **one level up from the web root** (as mrwweb suggested): a few months ago, an automatic update on a production server of ours killed php but left apache running. So everyone coming to the homepage was being offered index.php as a *download*. In theory, anybody who knew it was a WordPress site could have requested wp-config.php, and gotten it (had it been in the web root). Of course, they'd only be able to use those DB credentials if we allowed remote MySQL connections--but still, not cool. I realize this is a fringe case, but it's so easy to keep your config out of sight, why not do it?

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone has access via FTP, you don't need to worry about this. PHP is rendered on the server before it hit's the users browser.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another tip: protect wp-config.php (and any other sensitive files) with .htaccess

Add the following to an .htaccess file in your site's directory where all other WordPress files are located:

```
<Files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

from [How to harden your WordPress installation](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215302687-How-to-harden-your-WordPress-installation)

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has access to read the contents of your Php files, you've already been hacked.

Comment: or the web server's config got seriously borked to the point of just serving .php files as text ;-)